# user password reset e-mail

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Background

I'm using Woocommerce and Storefront theme

I'm creating 100's of users in bulk (potential customer list)

Over the coming 6 months I'm ring all those new users and via phone creating orders for them

The order e-mail goes to the (new) customer with a payment link (this all works fine)

However to pay via the link in the order the user (customer) needs to login to their account.

As I set up the accounts the customers don't have their passwords (and I possibly didn't have their e-mail addresses at the time of the bulk set-up anyway) or account ID's .

What I want to be able to do:
with 1st order they need to get their 1st order e-mail or a supplementary e-mail telling them their account ID and please set a password.
Subsequent orders (orders 2, 3, 4, ......)they do not need the password set-up e-mail.